Vue3 Jest Maska Error "Cannot find module 'maska/vue' from 'src/components/"
I am having a problem with a unit test using View3, Jest, and the Maska npm package. I think it's because the Maska npm project uses a sub folder for Vue. I import it like this:
import { vMaska } from "maska/vue";

It's the "/vue" part that is throwing it off but I don't know how to resolve this. Jest throws this error:

FAIL  tests/unit/XXXXX.test.spec.js
● Test suite failed to run
Cannot find module 'maska/vue' from 'src/components/XXXXXX"

